# Можно ли через POS API работать с собственным ККТ?

Tags: moysklad-pos-api

Использую POS API МоегоСлада, не могу найти как мне использоваться с этим апи собственный ККТ?

Comment: ККТ – Контрольно-кассовая техника? POS -- pos-терминал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по официальной документации https://online.moysklad.ru/api/posap/1.0/doc/index.html , такой возможности нет